# Dropdown selected value in second dropdownlist

Tags: php, sql, drop-down-menu, selecteditem, selectedvalue

I want to selected value from `"list_cust_name"` and want to pass it to another query to get the list of `"list_cust_city"`. This list will show city of the customer which is selected from `"list_cust_name"`. My table contains cust_id,cust_name,cust_city_cust_state.

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(function() {
 $('#list_cust_name').change(function(){
  $.ajax({
         url:'city.php',
        data:{cust_name:$( this ).val()},
        success: function( data ){
                $('#list_cust_city').html( data );
        }
 });
  });
  });
 </script>

 <label style="color:#000">Name </label>
 <?php $data_name = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT cust_name FROM customer_db ORDER BY    cust_name");?>

 <select id="list_cust_name" name="list_cust_name">
 <?php while($fetch_options_name = mysql_fetch_assoc($data_name)) { ?> 
 <option value="<?php=$fetch_options_name['cust_name']; ?>"><? php=$fetch_options_name['cust_name']; ?></option>
 <?php } ?>
 </select>

 <select id="list_cust_city" name="list_cust_city"></select>


 city.php

 <?php 
 include('dbconnect.php');
 db_connect();
  $cust_name1=$_GET['cust_name'];
  $data_city = mysql_query('SELECT DISTINCT cust_city FROM customer_db WHERE cust_name="'.$cust_name1.'" ORDER BY cust_city');
  while($fetch_options_city = mysql_fetch_assoc($data_city)) {
  ?> 
  <option value="<?php=$fetch_options_city['cust_city'];?>"><?php=$fetch_options_city['cust_city'];?></option>
  <?php
  }   
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed the id="list_cust_city" from the select, put it for a div that contains the select, the made the ajax return a full Select and put it inside that div. And added mysql_real_escape_string for the $*GET to protect from mysql injection. You should consider starting to use mysqli or PDO as mysql** is deprecated.

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(function() {
 $('#list_cust_name').change(function(){
  $.ajax({
         url:'city.php',
        data:{cust_name:$( this ).val()},
        success: function( data ){
                $('#list_cust_city').html( data );
        }
 });
  });
  });
 </script>

 <label style="color:#000">Name </label>
 <?php $data_name = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT cust_name FROM customer_db ORDER BY    cust_name");?>

 <select id="list_cust_name" name="list_cust_name">
 <?php while($fetch_options_name = mysql_fetch_assoc($data_name)) { ?> 
 <option value="<?php=$fetch_options_name['cust_name']; ?>"><? php=$fetch_options_name['cust_name']; ?></option>
 <?php } ?>
 </select>
 <div id="list_cust_city">
 <select name="list_cust_city"></select>
 </div>


 city.php

 <?php 
 include('dbconnect.php');
 db_connect();
  $cust_name1=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['cust_name']);
  $data_city = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT cust_city FROM customer_db WHERE cust_name='$cust_name1' ORDER BY cust_city");
?>
<select name="list_cust_city">
<?php
  while($fetch_options_city = mysql_fetch_assoc($data_city)) {
  ?> 
  <option value="<?php=$fetch_options_city['cust_city'];?>"><?php=$fetch_options_city['cust_city'];?></option>
  <?php
  }   
  ?>
</select>
```